# How was the photography Samurai Fiction/Kill Bill shadow scene made?

Tags: film-techniques, kill-bill

Kill Bill:

Fiction Samurai:

Help please!

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like they have a [rice-paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_paper) wall and either have a strongly colored light behind it, or a strong white light and the wall itself is colored. (My guess is that the light is colored, but I don't know for sure.)

They then don't light the foreground subjects at all, leaving them as only silhouettes.